# How to switch the case on button click

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using switch case with props in react, and on button click, I need to switch the case and show the data.

I have written the code, but don't know how to switch the case on button click

```
enum Statuses {
  SUCCESS = 'success',
  ERROR = 'error',
}

interface Props {
  confirmationStatus?: Statuses;
  error?: string;
}

public render() {
    return (
{this.getMessage()}
)
<button onClick={this.handleSubmit}> Submit </button>
}


private getMessage = () => {
    switch (this.props.confirmationStatus) {
      case Statuses.ERROR:
        return (
          <FormattedMessage {...messages.paymentError} />: reason

        );
      case Statuses.SUCCESS:
        return (         
            <FormattedMessage {...messages.paymentSuccess} />

        );
    }
  };

private handleSubmit = () => {
    const url = 'xxx';

    fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      mode: 'cors',
      method: 'PATCH',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        orderCode: this.state.orderId
      }),
    })
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(res => {
        this.state.resData = res;
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e));

    console.log(this.state.resData);
  };
}
```

Where should I write the code to switch the case using props

Comment: By Switch the case do you mean turn lowercase to uppercase?

Comment: sorry, but no i need to switch the case error or success..